# low-seg2cat not working all of the time

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat

My `{segment_3_category_name}` works on some pages and not on others

This page it works, it is where it says:All Bend Insensitive Fiber Products
http://cohr-dev-ee01.azurewebsites.net/lasers/main/bend-insensitive-fiber

This page it does not work:
http://cohr-dev-ee01.azurewebsites.net/lasers/laser/bif-780-l2-bif-rc-780-l2

It is where it says:All Products  it should say All Bend Insensitive Fiber Products  Cause both of these pages are part of the same category.

Comment: Is `bif-780-l2-bif-rc-780-l2` a category url title or an entry url title?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your category URL titles are unique, if you have duplicates that can cause this sort of problem.